# IP address string extraction not working in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-3.8

When attempting to extract the IP address from an 'ifconfig' command in Python3, I recieve the error:

File "testingCode.py", line 28, in 
ip = ip_string.strip().split(" ")[1:]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I'm not sure what is wrong because the code works in Python2, however when I switch to Python3, I get this error. I attempted to switch the .strip() command to .decode() and the program runs but doesn't output anything as the IP address from ifconfig is'nt found.
Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/local/lib/python3.8

import subprocess
import os

def bash(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', command])

def nmap_scan(ip):
    print(("Scanning TCP ports on %s" % ip))
    res = bash('nmap -T4 -p1-65535 | %s grep "open"' % ip).splitlines()
    ports = []

    for port in res:
        print(port)
        ports.append(port.split("/")[0])

    port_list = ",".join(ports)
    print("\nRunning intense scan on open ports...\n")
    bash('nmap -T4 -A -sV -p%s -oN output.txt %s' % (port_list, ip))
    print("Nmap intense scan  results logged in 'output.txt'")
    exit()

ip_string = bash('ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet "')

ip = ip_string.strip().split(" ")[1]

print(("Your IP Address is: " + ip + "\n"))

octets = ".".join(ip.split(".")[:-1])
subnet = octets + ".0/24"
print(("Running netdiscover on local subnet: %s" % subnet))

ips = bash('netdiscover -P -r %s | grep "1" | cut -d " " -f2 ' % subnet).splitlines()
for i in range(0, len(ips)):
    ip = ips[i]
    print(("%s - %s" % (i + 1, ip)))

choice = eval(input("\nEnter an option 1 - %s, or 0 to exit the script:\n" % len(ips)))
nmap_scan(ips[choice - 1])
```

Comment: Where does the `bash` function come from?

Comment: Is `ip_string` of type `bytes`? Then you should use `.decode()` before continueing with processing.

Comment: What output are you getting into ip_string variable? if it is a byte like object try `ip = str(ip_string.strip().split(" ")[1])`

Comment: Edited to show the full code

Comment: The error is on this line: ip = ip_string.strip().split(" ")[1]

Comment: @SURYATEJA, still gave the same error unfortionately

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a the fact that, when you execute something in a process, the communication is usually in bytes. Because of that the type of `ip_string` is bytes, not string. Try `ip = ip_string.decode("utf-8").strip().split(" ")[1]`. It creates a string from the bytes and splits that with the substring `" "`. If you for some reason wnat to have `ip` in bytes you can use `ip = ip_string.decode("utf-8").strip().split(" ")[1].encode("utf-8")`. This returns you the bytes, but I doesn't recomend it, because `__getitem__` works different with bytes as with strings. For example `"Hello"[0]` is not `H`, its the byte number of `H`.